# How is stock trading volume calculated?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, trading-volume

I want to ask whether the volume is the total amount of shares traded?
And half the volume is the number of shares bought and the other half is the number of shares sold.

It doesn't seem to make sense that there are more shares sold than bought, and bought than sold. Because if someone sells 100 shares, another person must buy those 100 shares.

Comment: If you buy a car, is one car traded, or are two cars traded?

Comment: any links for that, would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_(finance)

> ... the volume is commonly reported as the number of shares that changed hands during a given day...

Selling one share to someone would cause an increase of one, as only one share changed hands even if that transaction involved both a purchase and a sale.

Comment: Ahh okay, so shares are either buy amounts or sell amounts for the volume

Comment: There are two parties for every transaction. So for 100 shares, one buys 100 them and the other sells them and the traded volume is 100 shares.